# jqm - event for flipswitch, and how to get the value?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

How does a flipswitch work in jQuery mobile, and how to trigger an event that fires when it's changed (flipped)? Also, how to get it's current value (on / off)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **JQM** a flipswitch is like a checkbox, and can be either true or false. So reading what value it holds can be done with:

```
var a = $("#myFlip").prop("checked") ? "On" : "Off";
console.log(a);
```

To have an event that fires everytime the flipswitch is changed:

```
$("#myFlip").change(myToggle);       //event, calls myToggle()  

function myToggle(){ 
    var a = $("#myFlip").prop("checked") ? "On" : "Off";
    console.log(a);             
}
```

Html:

```
<form>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="checkbox-based-flipswitch-0">Checkbox-based:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myFlip" data-role="flipswitch">
    </div>
  </form>
```

That's all!